# How to display google map on my website by longitude and latitude

Tags: html, google-maps

I tried to use this code:

```
<img id="small-map" height="198" width="254" alt="Google Map" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=24.197611,120.780512" />
```

But it doesn't work on the html page.

Though when I use this one:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=24.197611,120.780512
```

it works but just as a google page

Answer (score 13, accepted):

hi here is the sample code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    var geocoder;
    function InitializeMap() {

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions =
        {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    }

    function FindLocaiton() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        InitializeMap();

        var address = document.getElementById("addressinput").value;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });

            }
            else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });

    }


    function Button1_onclick() {
        FindLocaiton();
    }

    window.onload = InitializeMap;

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Gecoding Demo JavaScript: </h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <input id="addressinput" type="text" style="width: 447px" />   
</td>
<td>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Find" onclick="return Button1_onclick()" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan ="2">
<div id ="map" style="height: 253px" >
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

See this doc https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-15.800513,-47.91378&zoom=11&size=200x200&sensor=false">
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply create link like:

```
"http://maps.google.com/?q=[lat],[long]"
```

for more details:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map

or for static image, try this:

```
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318
&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false"
```

for more details:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Answer (score 2):

Google provides more than ample documentation and samples to get you started -

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial